# addChild and removeCurrent child

Tags: actionscript-3, removechild, addchild

I have multiple buttons that load multiple movie clips. My problem is that when one loads it does not go away prevent the others to load when their button is clicked.  Here is my code below.  Do I need to add and "if" statement?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

```
movieButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoMovie);
webButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoWeb);
mailButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoMail);

 function gotoMovie(event:Event):void {
    var moviescene:MovieClip = new movie();
    stage.addChild(moviescene);
```

}

```
function gotoWeb(event:Event):void {
    var webscene:MovieClip = new web();
    stage.addChild(webscene);
```

}

```
function gotoMail(event:Event):void {
    var contactscene:MovieClip = new contact();
    stage.addChild(contactscene);
```

}

Comment: Would help if you tagged the language you are using.

Comment: Whoops! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what you want to achieve, but I guess this should help.

```
var currentScene:MovieClip; // pointer to scenes
movieButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoMovie);
webButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoWeb);
mailButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoMail);

// function that sets new scenes
function setScene(mc:MovieClip):void {
    if(currentScene) stage.removeChild(currentScene);// if a scene is already loaded, remove it
    currentScene = mc; // set currentScene to new scene
    stage.addChild(currentScene); // add it to stage
}

function gotoMovie(event:MouseEvent):void {
    setScene(new movie());
}

function gotoWeb(event:MouseEvent):void {
    setScene(new web());
}

function gotoMail(event:MouseEvent):void {
    setScene(new contact());
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this!  I've incorporated your script and now receiving an error.  Something is in your code is conflicting with some code I currently have within the file.  Going through it now.   Thank you again.